# Which CSS element is causing the problem on thtis website with this HTML module?

Tags: html, css

I have a webshop which is a half-closed system regarding the coding. I can put my custom HTML modules in the website, and can modify the base CSS but the site itself has a default 5490 line of CSS.

Please check the site here: https://thecard.hu

If you scroll to the bottom there is a pricing table HTML module, which I filled with the data I found here: `code`https://codepen.io/littlesnippets/pen/EVJVra

But when I put it on the site, the bottom part of the buttons are cut and I don't know why. I tried a few things but none worked.

An experienced HTML,CSS coder can spot the error immediately I suppose.

I've tried:

adding padding to id #customcontent10

modifying padding at .snip1214 .plan-select and at .snip1214 .featured .plan-select

I would like to have the outfit of the pricing table to be the same as on the source website. E.g. i don't want the bottom to be cropped

Thank you very much!

Comment: `.snip1214 {overflow: hidden; padding: 30px 0;}` will fix your problem. But your question is off-topic on SO, for multiple reasons. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear the float. Just add to your CSS

```css
.snip1214:after {
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: But I have another issue if you can help in that. It is not placed in the middle of the page. I used <center> tags in the HTML module and it did not help.. any tips for this?

Comment: the wrapper for the element should not have 100%. It should have the element width and give them than a ```margin: 40px auto 40px auto;```

Comment: I tried so many things based on your comment but none of them is working... what do you mean specifiacally by the wrapper? the .snip1214? I tried to modify that width, max width with all combinations and did not work :( Appreciate your help Daniel!

Comment: at first you have to remove the ```center``` tag, than remove the ```width: 1920px;``` from you snip1214 or set the width to auto. At the the snip1214 the max-width (for example) to ```max-width: 50vw;```. Now change the ```.snip1214 .plan``` width to ```width: calc(100% / 3);```. Than it should be centered.

Answer (score 0):

the bottom part is cut because

in your css

```
    .customcontent .middle{
      overflow:hidden
     }
```

the below will no longer hide if you use

```
.customcontent .middle{
    overflow:visible 
}
```

or simple delete the css

Answer (score 0):

So, what you should do is add this (or something like it) to your CSS:

```css
div#middle-tablazat {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

That should fix the problem. It is being clipped because of the way `inline-block`, which is how you're displaying the plan button `a` tags, handles its size. Just add padding to the main container `div` (`#middle-tablazat`) and you'll be fine.